# VBA : wrong formula - freezing and not enough memory message

Tags: vba, formula

I have a code on VBA that makes my Excel freezing (filling cells) and gives a output message like "not enough memory to run" + error 1004, but I don't understand why because it's really a simple formula.. There's only one part of the full code that causes the issue and here is it:

```
 Sub mismatches()
 Dim sht As Worksheet, cell As Range, areaToTrim As Range, LastRow As Long
 LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mismatches")
 sht.Activate
 Range("O1").EntireColumn.Insert
 sht.Cells(1, 15) = "Mismatch DRP"
 Range("02:0" & LastRow).Value = _
 "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(K2,CDL_data!D:D,1,0)),""N/A"",I2)"
 Range("02:0" & LastRow).Select
 Selection.Copy
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
 SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

I'd like to precise that the other parts of the code are almost exactly the same, only the formula is different, but they run properly! Something has to be "wrong" or "too heavy" in the formula, even if I've already used this kind of formula. I've tried the full code with only 3 rows (on sheet "Mismatches") but there are 9000 rows in the sheet "CDL_data" (used for the Vlookup).

Comment: should it not be .formula? not .value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a typo, using zero instead of the letter O in the column reference. This means that you are referencing a number of whole rows, probably 9000 of them and inserting a Vlookup function into 16384 cells per row, which is roughly 147 Million cells that will need to calculate the Vlookup.

You probably want to change this part of the code from using a zero

```
 Range("02:0" & LastRow).Value = _
 "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(K2,CDL_data!D:D,1,0)),""N/A"",I2)"
 Range("02:0" & LastRow).Select
```

to this, using the letter O as the column reference:

```
 Range("O2:O" & LastRow).Value = _
 "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(K2,CDL_data!D:D,1,0)),""N/A"",I2)"
 Range("O2:O" & LastRow).Select
```

You may want to change your VBE font to something that uses a distinctly different character for Zero as compared to uppercase O, to avoid such mistakes. Consolas uses a diagonal strike on a zero, which makes it very easy to distinguish it from an O.

In general, if you want your code to run faster, avoid selecting things and then acting on selections. In most cases it is possible to act on the range directly.

Comment: Yes indeed, it works now!! Thank you for this precious help teylyn :) I'm still a beginner in VBA..May I ask you one more thing ? Could you please show me, in this case, how to act on the range directly ? Thanks